# When should I use circle notation for interfaces

Tags: uml, class-diagram

According to UML Superstructure Specification, v2.4 there are two different notations for interfaces in UML class diagrams. One of them is usual box with "interface" word and name above and another one is a cirle with name above (uncle Bob calls it lollipop).
The question is - when should I use circle notation? Is it suitable for situations when class implimenting this interface has only public methods defined in interface? So if it used only througt interface - method set in interface is obvious and maybe I could use this circle notation.
Help me with this, please. Specification is quite clear about semi-circle notation but not about circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a matter of taste. Both notations (lollipop and rectangular with stereotype) are interchangeable and have the same semantics.

However, since the rectangular notation allows for showing operations it is preferred if you need to show them. Otherwise the lollipops use up less space which is preferred in other cases.

Comment: In these terms, I would add that you may use the box notation when you need a verbose and comprehensive interface description. When you are going to describe all the methods and be specific in their arguments. Lollipop may be used when you just want to mention that a class implements an interface, and you don't want to dig into it too much. For instance, `Serializable`, `Codable`, etc. Something well-known.